Playwright - SSL configuration setup for certification using java
I'm developing a POC using Playwright Java and I face error related to Bad certification, I understand that we need to have a method to handle the certs which are handled in Keystore and trustore respectively.
Error Message :
Step failed
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='write EPROTO A4650000:error:0A000412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 42

  name='Error
  stack='Error: write EPROTO A4650000:error:0A000412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 42

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16)
}

I have tried to set the "setIgnoreHTTPSErrors" as true, but my service demands certs for the response. How can I set certificate in Playwright using Java?
